# Adjust Keyboard to show the content behind it in IOS

Tags: ios, keyboard

I have a form in vc . In the form there are some field and textviews. When user click the text area keyboard popup , and user start typing on it. But the issue is coming the textview hides behind the keyboard and user can't see what he/she is writing. Is there any way that user can not get this issue? The screen looks like this
[image]

Comment: use TPKeyboardAvoiding library.

Comment: I had the same problem. Make you view scrollable, this way you can scroll your view until the textView is visible. This is how i solved my problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you move the views up when the keyboard appears and down when the keyboard disappears. If you want to do so:

You will only need a ScrollView if the contents you have now do not fit in the iPhone screen. (If you are adding the ScrollView as the superview of the components. just to make the TextField scroll up when keyboard comes up, then it's not needed.)
For showing the textfields without being hidden by the keyboard, the standard way is to move up/down the view having textfields whenever the keyboard is shown.
Here is some sample code:

```
#define kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD 80.0

-(void)keyboardWillShow {
    // Animate the current view out of the way
    if (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
    {
        [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
    }
    else if (self.view.frame.origin.y < 0)
    {
        [self setViewMovedUp:NO];
    }
}

-(void)keyboardWillHide {
    if (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
    {
        [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
    }
    else if (self.view.frame.origin.y < 0)
    {
        [self setViewMovedUp:NO];
    }
}

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender
{
    if ([sender isEqual:mailTf])
    {
        //move the main view, so that the keyboard does not hide it.
        if  (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
        {
            [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
        }
    }
}

//method to move the view up/down whenever the keyboard is shown/dismissed
-(void)setViewMovedUp:(BOOL)movedUp
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3]; // if you want to slide up the view

    CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
    if (movedUp)
    {
        // 1. move the view's origin up so that the text field that will be hidden come above the keyboard 
        // 2. increase the size of the view so that the area behind the keyboard is covered up.
        rect.origin.y -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
        rect.size.height += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
    }
    else
    {
        // revert back to the normal state.
        rect.origin.y += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
        rect.size.height -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
    }
    self.view.frame = rect;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // register for keyboard notifications
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    // unregister for keyboard notifications while not visible.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your form into its own View, and then simply adjust the View's bottom constraint when the keyboard appears/disappears.

To enable a notification for when the keyboard appears, add the following line to viewDidLoad:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
```

And implement keyboardWillShow to raise the constraint above the keyboard view when it appears:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let info = notification.userInfo {
        let rect: CGRect = info["UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey"] as! CGRect //get the keyboard frame as CGRect to get its dimensions
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.formViewBottomConstraint?.constant = rect.height + 14 //replace 14 with your desired pixel offset from the top of the keyboard
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
}
```

Finally, when your keyboard disappears, reset your view's bottom constraint to its original value:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        self.formViewBottomConstraint?.constant = 14
        return true
}
```

The above code will simply slide the whole view above the keyboard, but if you want to slide the view up and down so that each text field is right above the keyboard (and it adjusts for each text field), then just set the bottom constraint relative to the textField's frame.origin.y when the keyboard appears.